# How to jump to a particular page with UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm using Xcode 8's default Page-based application, and I'm stuck trying to jump to a particular page (as opposed to swiping left and right to turn). I have found similar questions on StackOverflow, but the answers mostly suggested using this method:

```
 setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion
```

I don't need to change the number of pages to be displayed, so can I avoid using `setViewControllers`?

After reading through Xcode's page-based application template, I think this function may work:

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(_ index: Int, storyboard: UIStoryboard) -> DataViewController?
```

However, I don't know where to get the parameter `storyboard: UIStoryboard`, since ModelController (the controller that serves as UIPageViewControllerDataSource) isn't part of the storyboard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45026010/5461400

Comment: try this :http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: thank you! I read your answer; is it correct that when using setViewControllers, one can just put in 1 "page" to be displayed?

Comment: You can put ViewController in array like:  [Your View Controller]

Comment: but why is it an array? I thought that only one page can be displayed on the screen Could you explain what setViewControllers method does exactly? Thanks so much

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view controllers passed to this method are those that will be visible after the animation has completed. Use a data source to provide additional view controllers to which users navigate.

When defining a page view controller interface, you can provide the content view controllers one at a time (or two at a time, depending upon the spine position and double-sided state) or as-needed using a data source. When providing content view controllers one at a time, you use the 
`setViewControllers(_:direction:animated:completion:)`
 method to set the current content view controllers. To support gesture-based navigation, you must provide your view controllers using a data source object.

The data source for a page view controller is responsible for providing the content view controllers on demand and must conform to the 
`UIPageViewControllerDataSource`
protocol.

The delegate object—an object that conforms to the 
`UIPageViewControllerDelegate`
 protocol—provides some appearance-related information and receives notifications about gesture-initiated transitions.

```
setViewControllers([<#Your ViewControllers#>], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**More Info**

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/1614087-setviewcontrollers?language=objc)

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17559518/5461400)

Comment: This is so helpful! Can you check if i'm understanding this correctly: I can provide viewControllers one or two at a time when I need to jump to a page, and still use the datasource object to support gesture navigation?

Comment: yup .. setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion only sets the visible view controllers

Comment: It makes sense to me now, and i should probably read apple's official doc thoroughly before posting here in the future. thanks!